# JQuery grid doesn't show data - show empty grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can anybody help me with the jQuery plugin jqGrid? I downloaded [jqGrid 4.4.5](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) and I put in code

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
             jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ url:'test.json', datatype: "json", colNames:['Inv No','Date'], colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', width:55}, {name:'date',index:'date', width:90}], rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30], pager: '#pager2', sortname: 'id', viewrecords: true, sortorder: "desc", caption:"USERS" }); jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});

        });
    </script>
```

I have in my html table

```
  <table id="list2"></table>
  <div id="pager2"></div>
```

and I have test.json like

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": ""
    }
]
```

but when I load page I don't get any data in grid just like on picture [image].

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQgrid is awesome! But the documentation is not very well...

In your case the problem is the Json data... If you look [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data) in the JSON DATA part then you realize that the Json you're trying to use in not valid for JQGrid...

Must respect this format :

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

Check the link and read beacause is not too simply...